# Efficient matrix constructions from column-by-column comparison

Tags: r, matrix

As a follow-up question to [Efficient ways of creating matrix based on vector matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64104342/efficient-ways-of-creating-matrix-based-on-vector-matches), how would I go about if I would like to produce a boolean matrix with matches between each column in `Y` and `X`:

```
X <- data.frame(
  x1 = c('dog', 'cow', 'horse', 'rabbit', 'bear', 'seal', 'lion', 'ostrich','cat', 'hamster'),
  x2 = c(NA, 'dog', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 'hamster',NA, NA),
  x3 = c('ostrich', NA, NA, NA, 'bear', NA, NA, NA,NA, NA)
)

Y <- data.frame(
  y1 = c('beaver', 'crow', 'donkey', 'lion', 'bear', 'fox', 'moose', 'mole'),
  y2 =  c(NA, NA, NA, 'bear', NA, NA, 'moose', NA)
)
```

The expected output in this case would be two matrices, equivalent to what is produced by `outer(... FUN = "==")`:

```
> outer(X$x1, Y$y1, FUN = "==")
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]
 [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[10,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

outer(X$x2, Y$y2, FUN = "==")
      [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4] [,5] [,6]  [,7] [,8]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA   NA FALSE   NA   NA FALSE   NA
 [3,]   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
 [4,]   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
 [5,]   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
 [6,]   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
 [7,]   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
 [8,]   NA   NA   NA FALSE   NA   NA FALSE   NA
 [9,]   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
[10,]   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
```

I'm hesitant to use loop-like functions because of performance. Vectorized approaches would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are after, but perhaps something like this?

```
l <- min(lengths(list(X, Y)))
Map(function(x, y) outer(x, y, FUN = '=='), X[seq_len(l)], Y[seq_len(l)])
```

Result:

```
$x1
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]
 [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[10,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$x2
      [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4] [,5] [,6]  [,7] [,8]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA   NA FALSE   NA   NA FALSE   NA
 [3,]   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
 [4,]   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
 [5,]   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
 [6,]   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
 [7,]   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
 [8,]   NA   NA   NA FALSE   NA   NA FALSE   NA
 [9,]   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
[10,]   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
```

Note that `Map` is still a "loop-like function", however.

Comment: Thank you, that works, although I was hoping for something quicker :)

Comment: You can easily do this in parallel, using e.g. `parallel::clusterMap`, or `future.apply::future_Map`.

Comment: oh la la, haven't checked into parallel computing yet, but this is definitely a reason to do so. thanks!